# How to return different entity reference fields from multiple bundles using the same name with JSON:API?

Tags: entities, 9

### The Goal

My site structure looks like this:

- Node content type **A** with entity reference field **groupA** pointing to a term with field **groupAfield**
- Node content type **B** with entity reference field **groupB** pointing to a term with field **groupBfield**

I want to be able to get content types A and B from a single JSON:API endpoint, and I want this endpoint to return groupB as groupA (rename groupB to groupA for nodes of content type B in the output).

This is to simplify the output for clients consuming JSON:API.

### What I have tried

JSON:API usually only returns one bundle at a time.  However, using the [JSON:API Resources module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_resources), you can create your own custom resource that returns multiple entity types (using an entity query).

So I made a custom resource type.

I need to include the field values for both groupA and groupB, which I did like this:

```
$request->query->set('include', 'nodeTypeA.groupA.groupAfield','nodeTypeB.groupB.groupBfield');
```

This correctly gets all the data I need.  So the last step is to rename `groupB` to `groupA` in the output.  This is where I'm having trouble.

Normally, I would use the [JSON:API Extras module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) to rename `groupB` to `groupA` for content type B.  However, I cannot do this for my custom resource because then the `include` statement will break (because `nodeTypeA`'s group does not have `groupBField`, and `nodeTypeB`'s group does not have `groupAField`).

So, I need to do the renaming after JSON:API has done its processing:

```
$data = $this->loadResourceObjectDataFromEntityQuery($entity_query, $cacheability);
$response = $this->createJsonapiResponse($data, $request, 200, []);
```

But, this seems to be too late to change the output.  Is there some way I can rename `groupB` to `groupA` just before returning the response?

Answer (score 1):

From a #decoupled Slack conversation, bbrala (JSON:API maintainer) stated:

> Don't think there is a supported way to do that other than extending
> and overwriting the controller that handles responses. Other modules
> do that too, but this will make the maintenance burden of you
> application higher and probably break some modules you might use.

One way to work around this would be to use [Dynamic Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference), but [there are several issues that must be solved before DER and JSON:API can be used together](https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference/issues/3315145).